# jQuery display select box options in text field (each option text in seperate textfield) dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to dynamically update the option values from select box dropdown.

First, I need to create number of input fields dynamically based on count of select box options.
Eg: If my select box has 3 options (except first **-- Select --** option), I need to create 3 input fields and their values should be from selectbox, first input element value should be **Option 1**, second one will be **Option 2** etc....

Please refer the below screenshot and code:

**Expected results:**

[image]

**What I am getting:**

[image]

```js
var optionValues = [];

$('#selectbox option').each(function() {
    optionValues.push($(this).text());
});

$('#result').append('<input type="text" value="" class="selectbox_options" val="'+optionValues+'" />');

$('.selectbox_options').val(optionValues);
```

```css
body{font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;}
select{width:260px;padding:5px;margin-bottom:20px;background:#f2fdff;border:1px solid #000000;}
input{width:250px;padding:5px;border:radius:0;border:1px solid #000000;display:block;display:block;margin-bottom:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectbox">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wr5qapmt/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.map

```js
const html = $('#selectbox option').map(function() { 
  if (this.value) { // ignore the empty option
    return `<input type="text" class="selectbox_options" value="${this.textContent}" />`
  }
}).get().join("<br/>")
    
$("#result").html(html)
```

```css
body{font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;}
select{width:260px;padding:5px;margin-bottom:20px;background:#f2fdff;border:1px solid #000000;}
input{width:250px;padding:5px;border:radius:0;border:1px solid #000000;display:block;display:block;margin-bottom:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectbox">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```